# Geometrically relating the solution to $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$, and the cross product of vectors $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

I recently came across two lines of the form $a_{1}x+b_{1}y+c_{1}=0$ and $a_{2}x+b_{2}y+c_{2}=0$.

I had noticed that, assuming the two lines intersect, if we multiply the cross product of the vectors $(a_{1},b_{1},c_{1})$ and $(a_{2},b_{2},c_{2})$ by a scalar such that the $z$ component of that vector is $1$, then the resulting first two elements of that vector is the solution to this system of equations.

I was wondering why this is true or if there exists a proof regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a plane $$ax+by+cz=k$$one normal vector to this plane is $(a,b,c)$.

In particular, given planes $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=a_2x+b_2+c_2z=0$, the normal vectors $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ are such that the planes consist of all vectors (based at the origin) normal to the chosen normal vectors.

That's useful, because the cross product $(v_1,v_2,v_3)=(a_1,b_1,c_1)\times(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ is normal to both vectors, and thus, as a point, is in both planes.

If $v_3=0$, it isn't hard to see that the two lines were parallel. If not, since the planes are linear subspaces, the vector $v'=\left(\frac{v_1}{v_3},\frac{v_2}{v_3},1\right)$ is also in both planes.

Thus, we have $$a_1\cdot\frac{v_1}{v_3}+b_1\cdot\frac{v_2}{v_3}+c_1\cdot1=0$$$$a_2\cdot\frac{v_1}{v_3}+b_2\cdot\frac{v_2}{v_3}+c_2\cdot1=0$$But this just means that $\left(\frac{v_1}{v_3},\frac{v_2}{v_3}\right)$ is the solution.